# Alternative for using a cron job

Tags: cron

There is a file having default content existing in it. I need to append a set of commands to this file and have it in the file all the time. But, my changes are flushed twice every hour due to puppet configuration. I need some way to keep my changes persistent in the file. Cron cannot be used because the Cron file also get flushed because of the puppet.

Comment: Work with puppet, not against it. Fix your puppet configuration.

Comment: If it's running a web server you can send it a message from a cron job running on a more persistent server.  That is, set up a script page with some basic security (shared secret, send time and hash of (time+secret)) and GET it in the cron job on the other server.

Comment: @Dave S , it doesn't have web server